# What escapes to the heap?

Tags: go, memory-management, unsafe, unsafe-pointers

I have this piece of code, which is supposed to do no allocations at all, but for some reason it does. As benchmarks say, there happens 2 allocs/op.

Which lines of the functions do the allocation and why?

The functions:

```golang
func (vi *VarInt /* int32 */) Read(input io.Reader) error {
    var (
        b     byte
        buf   = unsafe.Slice(&b, 1)
        shift int
        value uint32
    )
    for {
        _, err := io.ReadFull(input, buf)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        value |= (uint32(b) & 0b01111111) << shift

        if (b & 0b10000000) == 0 {
            *vi = VarInt(value)
            return nil
        }

        shift += 7
        if shift >= 32 {
            return ErrVarIntTooLong
        }
    }
}

func (vi *VarInt /* int32 */) Write(output io.Writer) error {
    var (
        varint [5]byte
        uvalue = uint32(*vi)
        x      int
    )
    for ; ; x++ {
        vb := uint8(uvalue)

        if (vb & 0b10000000) == 0 {
            varint[x] = vb
            break
        }

        varint[x] = (vb & 0b01111111) | 0b10000000

        uvalue >>= 7
    }

    _, err := output.Write(varint[:x+1])
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The benchmark:

```golang
func BenchmarkVarInt(b *testing.B) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    buf.Grow(5)
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        vi := (VarInt)(i)
        vi.Write(&buf)
        vi.Read(&buf)
        buf.Reset()
    }
}
```

I suppose the `buf` slice somehow escapes, but I can't figure out how, because as far as I understand a slice is a struct allocated on the stack in this case, which would point to the variable `b` as its data. I tried changing the expression `unsafe.Slice(&b, 1)` to `(*[1]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))[:]`, but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a value is boxed in an interface, it's always considered to escape — even if the value is never used outside of the call stack, Go just stops the analysis at that point and considers that someone might have gotten hold of the address, and therefore the value has to go on the heap.

Since `Read` takes `io.Reader` and `Write` takes `io.Writer`, `buf` (which is a `bytes.Buffer` passed to both functions) has to escape.

Even if you made those functions take the concrete type `bytes.Buffer` (which you presumably don't want), that wouldn't be enough because `Read` calls `io.ReadFull` which again takes an `io.Reader` . You'd have to work harder than that to make this allocation-free.

As a side note, there's a much easier solution to your other issue in `Read` that doesn't require any `unsafe.Slice` shenanigans: just replace `var b byte` with `var b [1]byte` (which is *exactly the same* in memory), pass `b[:]` to `ReadFull`, and use `b[0]` in the other places you use `b`.